# What does total_qty_ordered in sales_order table mean?

Tags: magento2, database, sales-order

We currently migrate our old Shop Database into Magento.

So we try to understand the table fields of Magento.

First: Do you know an documentation about the Magento database fields and their meanings?

What does total_qty_ordered in sales_order table mean? What value is saved in this field?

Comment: magento does not have any document for tables . total_qty_ordered means total no of qty for an order. Suppose an order has two items, Item A has placed X qty and Item B placed Y qty, So total_qty_ordered = X+Y

Comment: @AmitBera Thank you for your answer. I'm not able to upvote your comment. Could you please create an answer so that I can upvote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento Official Documentation - Common Magento Tables

https://docs.magento.com/mbi/data-analyst/data-warehouse-mgr/sales-flat-order-table.html

> **total_qty_ordered**: Total quantity of items included in the order. Calculated by joining sales_order.entity_id to sales_order_item.order_id and summing the sales_order_item.qty_ordered field

https://docs.magento.com/mbi/data-analyst/data-warehouse-mgr/common-mage-tables.html
https://docs.magento.com/mbi/data-analyst/data-warehouse-mgr/entity-rel-diag.html